# Calling another sub then returning to first sub to continue (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, subprocess, call

Is it possible to have a function  that cuts to another function and when that step is complete return to the first fuction again...? at the moment I can only switch to another sub but not return and continue where I left
example:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        msgbox("Hello step 1")

        Call SECONDSTEP()

        msgbox("Hello step3")
end sub
```

Comment: What is your code in SECONDSTEP()

Comment: How did you conclude that control does return from the nested sub?

Comment: Ignore `Call`, it's completely unnecessary and is partially a leftover from VB6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your execution will always return to calling function. in this example three message box display in sequence step1, step2, step3. But if sub function contain `close()` then execution will not return to calling function.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MsgBox("step 1")

        Call SECONDSTEP()

        MsgBox("step3")
    End Sub

    Private Sub SECONDSTEP()
        MsgBox("step2")
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you do something like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        msgbox("Hello step 1")

        Dim a As Integer
        a = GiveMeSomeAnswers(21,2)

        msgbox("The answer is"& a)
End Sub

Private Function GiveMeSomeAnswers(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer

   Return x*y

End Sub
```

If will run the first messagebox (Hello Step 1) and then run the second function
which multiplies x and y and then return back to the first method and give you a second messagebox that says (The answer is 42).

Comment: Thats a good point also JaggenSWE... Im however only permitted to accept one answer :)